# Trying to conduct a Stepwise LDA in R but keep receiving an error message

Tags: r, linear-discriminant

I am running a stepwise LDA to look at how to discriminant against two groups (P vs NP) based on 4 variables. I ran the lda function with no problems but when I try to do the stepwise function I get this message:

```
Error in if (any(member < 0) || any(member > 1)) stop("membership values (posterior probabilities)",  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

this is my line for the forward LDA
stepclass(ï..Pregnancy.State ~ Rad.Length+Circ.Length+Area+X.Collagen.Content, data=both.pulm, method="lda", fold=35, direction="forward")

I ran this on 3 other groups as well with no problems